# How to fix error while installing NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have installed Java and am trying to install NetBeans 11.3 on my Windows 10 but after I ran the exe. installer, an error message popped up:

> An unexpected exception happened in  thread main
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError java/util/jar/Pack200

Comment: I suspect you are using Java 14, I have a feeling they have removed Pack200 in that version. Try with an older version of Java.

Comment: @mwarren that's not just a feeling: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/367

Comment: Use a version of java supported by the version of netbeans you have.

Comment: The NetBeans installer will be run by your JDK registered with the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable. If you have earlier JDK installed, you may temporarily point  "JAVA_HOME" to any pre-Java 14 JDK, which would have no problem installing NetBeans. After the installation done, you would change your "JAVA_HOME"  back to JDK 14 if you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NetBeans have problems with the jdk-14, because I suppose that you have install the jdk-14 so uninstall it and try it with the jdk-13.0.2.

Comment: thank you and everyone who commented this! I've installed 12 instead and netbeans working fine!

Comment: This solution should be combined with @Felistrix solution. Running an older JDK is not the right solution. I just did this and everything works fine, plus I have the latest JDK.

Answer (score 9):

Sorry, but in my opinion is to install an old version from Java no solution, just because it works. When someone has problems with his Firewall, simply disable the Firewall would also be no solution.

> https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/other_jreversions.xml
>   We highly recommend users remove all older versions of Java from your
>   system. Keeping old and unsupported versions of Java on your system
>   presents a serious security risk. Removing older versions of Java from
>   your system ensures that Java applications will run with the most
>   up-to-date security and performance improvements on your system.

The "real" solution would be a reprogramming of the NetBeans installer.
This used function was suggested for deprecated on 2018-04-04, which was done on 2018-08-23.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8200752
The removal was suggested on 2019-10-08, which was done on 2019-12-18.
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8232022

> https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8232022
>   We assume that developers who rely on Pack200 have had enough notice about its proposed removal to make alternative arrangements. … We assume that developers who use `pack200` to shrink application JARs can switch to either the `jlink` tool or the `jpackage` tool to create application-specific runtimes with an optimized form factor.

edit: I solved it this way.

1. uninstalled JDK 14
2. installed JDK 13.0.2
3. installed Apache NetBeans
4. installed JDK 14
5. open C:\Program Files\NetBeans\netbeans\etc\netbeans.conf and changed path to JDK
6. uninstalled JDK 13.0.2

Now NetBeans runs with the JDK 14.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I got it working as follows from cmd, when referring to older version:
Apache-NetBeans-11.3-bin-windows-x64.exe --javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2"

Answer (score 3):

The **https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb113/nb113.html** site now  has this
memo:

*The installers will not run under JDK 14 because usage is made of the Pack200 Tools and API, for packing and unpacking, which is removed in JDK 14, see JEP 367.*

Answer (score 2):

If several JDK versions are installed, then you need to define the environment variable "JAVA_HOME" where to set the path to JDK-12. 
Details are described [here](https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/update_runtime_settings.xml). (Only in Russian)

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way to Andy's.
(Windows)
1) Right click on "Apache-NetBeans-11.3-bin-windows-x64" installer and select "Create shortcut".
2) Right click on the created shortcut and select "Properties".
3) In the "target" textbox, add your under 14 JDK version path at the end, here is how mine looks like:

> C:\Users\userfoldername\Desktop\Apache-NetBeans-11.3-bin-windows-x64.exe **--javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13"**

4) Press Ok when done, double-click on the shortcut and it should install fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to openJDK 12 worked for me too. But instead of uninstalling JDKs or manually changing the env, I use [Sdkman.io](https://sdkman.io) which works like Node version manager if you have used that. It manages your JDKS for you and offers downloads of different versions (Open, Zulu, Graals) and will switch between them with with just a quick command.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice solution in 3 steps:

1. check all versions of the JDK path in Environment variables, if there is an outdated path please remove it and keep the latest version of the Java JDK bin path.
2. after the second step, please uninstall the Netbeans and re-install the latest version.
3. Netbeans will found the latest JDK path in case it was jdk14 and choose JDK latest version path for NetBeans.
   **solved**

Answer (score 0):

Just install JRE from oracle. Everthing will run fine. I have the same issue