# I can't install Apache NetBeans plugins with JDK 14 installed

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-plugins, java-14, netbeans-12

I've got JDK 14 installed, and I can't install NetBeans plugins. After looking carefully at what exactly happened, it seems like NetBeans plugins are installed using the Pack200 API, which was removed in JDK 14. I don't think Apache is aware of this old NetBeans way of installing NetBeans plugins, so is there a workaround to this? I'm using Apache NetBeans 12.0, if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix error while installing NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60771107/how-to-fix-error-while-installing-netbeans)

Comment: @JoachimRohde Thanks for the link, but it doesn't match my question. The question that you provided was about a Pack200 error when installing NetBeans, but my question is about a Pack200 error when installing NetBeans plugins. I'll be looking forward for answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been discussed on the [mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/rfe3fdd4da9ea1f86658d692bc28b0c04d8e695bf5dfbba04daa872a6%40%3Cusers.netbeans.apache.org%3E).
There's also a [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2842) for it that mentions a few work-arounds. One of them: use an old JDK for installing the plugin (and switch back to JDK 14 after that) or as an alternative copy `/jdk-13/bin/pack200` to `/jdk-14/bin` (or set a symbolic link).

Comment: Thanks! However, I did try this once. At the time, I had both JDK 13.0.2 and JDK 14 installed, and I switched the environment variables over to JDK 13, and I tried it again, and it still wasn't working. P.S. Finally, I know that at the time, NetBeans was recognizing JDK 13, not JDK 14, so this is strange. Thanks for the answer, anyways!

Comment: Well, I didn't copy pack200, since I didn't even think of that. Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: It'll be partly fixed in Apache NetBeans 12.2; NetBeans will ask the user to select a Java installation that has pack200, such as JDK 13.0.2. I'm still waiting for Apache NetBeans 12.1 to be released.